# Laravel Homestead: Migrations do not occur on shared host's database

Tags: php, database, laravel-4

I have created a project using Laravel Homestead PHP and it is running fine within my development environment locally.  Now I want to deploy my Laravel PHP app to a shared host on HostGator.

I have created a new database within my HostGator account and now I wish to upload data onto this live database.

So far I've tried editing the file **database.php** within my project's **config** folder using the live database host's information.  However when I try running migrations, database tables are not created within my live database.

Here is my project's **database.php** file:

```
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'MY_HOSTGATOR_IP_ADDRESS',
        'database'  => 'MY_DATABASE_NAME',
        'username'  => 'DATABASE_USERNAME',
        'password'  => 'DATABASE_USERNAME_PASSWORD',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

Is there another file I need to edit within my Laravel Homestead project that will establish a connection to my live database?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any errors you can see? There's a lot that could cause this issue, so it's hard to debug without knowing specifically what's happening.

Comment: @TimLewis After I perform a migration using 'php artisan migrate' within my terminal, it is still creating the database tables in my local database that I've named 'homestead' instead of creating the tables on my live HostGator database.

Comment: Ok, I'll make a quick answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of places where you can define your database connections. By default, you'll define them here:

```
app/config/database.php
```

Notice also, that your Laravel Installation has this folder:

```
app/config/local/database.php
```

Whenever I migrate a project to a live server, I add the following folder and files into Laravel:

```
app/config/production/app.php
app/config/production/database.php
```

The changes you make in this folder (including any database connections in `database.php` will be the settings used by Laravel when you're in your production environment. To check the current environment, use:

```
php artisan env
```

It should say production by default, unless you've changed these settings in `bootstrap/start.php`:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
  'local' => array('local_computer_name'),
  'production' => array('server_name') 
));
```

For example, my local Virtual Box has a name of `timpc`, so setting `'local' => array('timpc')` would cause `php artisan env` to echo "Local".

Hopefully that helped, here's the TL:DR

- Create a folder in app/config called `production`
- Create the files `app.php` and `database.php` and modify them as needed for your production environment.
- Make sure you have the setting in `bootstrap/start.php` that applies your server's name to the `Production` environment.

That should solve the issue you are facing. If not, there's is something else wrong. Quick questions, have you pushed the Laravel Project to HostGator using Git or something similar? I assume you have, and you're using HostGator's CLI to call `php artisan migrate`, but if not, that would be the issue.

Cheers!

Comment: This looks really good!  I'll definitely keep you posted with my progress and how well my app gets deployed, thank you!